# python how to search an item in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, nested-lists

say I have this list:

```
li = [["0", "20", "ar"], ["20", "40", "asdasd"], ["50", "199", "bar"], ["24", "69", "sarkozy"]]
```

Now, forget about the numbers, they are something that let me recognize the position of string. So basically, given that I have the string "ar" in hand, how can I extract all the lists that contain "ar"?

```
new_li = [["50", "199", "bar"], ["24", "69", "sarkozy"]]
```

How can I obtain this list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> [x for x in li if 'ar' in x[2]]
[['0', '20', 'ar'], ['50', '199', 'bar'], ['24', '69', 'sarkozy']]
```

Comment: Good answer to the question as posed, but also consider that your data structure might be inefficient regarding your problem space.